# Refreshing in react router, component lifecycle

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I have a component that looks like this:

```
class ThingView extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.loadThingThenFrames(this.props.id)
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        console.log("did update")
        if (prevProps.id !== this.props.id) {
            this.props.loadThingThenFrames(this.props.id)
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                { this.props.isRequesting ? <p>Loading thing...</p> : null}
                <h1> {this.props.thing ? this.props.thing.device_id : "Thing Not Found"} </h1>
                <Timeline frames={this.props.frames} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
    thing: state.thingView.thing,
    frames: state.thingView.frames,
    id: ownProps.params.id,
    isRequesting: state.thingView.isRequesting,
    requestError: state.thingView.requestError
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    loadThingThenFrames: (id) => { dispatch(loadThingThenFrames(id)) }
})
```

This component is rendered when `things/:id`. According to the [react-router docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ComponentLifecycle.md), `componentDidUpdate` gets called when the props are changed, for example when a thing is selected from a list of things. I want to `loadThingThenFrames` when the page is refreshed, or if someone leaves `ThingView` and then comes back to `ThingView` with the same `thing`. Currently, this doesn't happen since the previous `props.id` is the same as the current `props.id` if I remove this check, then there's an infinite loop of props getting updated and `componentDidUpdate` being called.

Answer (score 1):

It think the problem is that `componentDidUpdate` is not called for the initial render (when component is mounted) - it's called only when component is re-rendered. So it's not called after page refresh or when you come back to component route because component is mounted in such cases (not re-rendered) - new instance of component is created and inserted into DOM.

So besides calling `loadThingThenFrames` when component is updated you should also  call `loadThingThenFrames` when component is mounted - in component constructor or another lifecycle method that is called when component is mounted (`componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount`). Please check [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html) for more details about ccomponents lifecycle.